# Convert date to Unicode variant and emoji for iPhone

Tags: shortcut, text, time, smart-keyboard

To cope with

1. truncated WhatsApp when replying to chats,
2. Late replying to chats that mention like yesterday or tomorrow. misleading when not replying on same day.

I rather use date and time but run into longer text. I use emojis and Unicodes. Like month January is replaced with ㋀; 18pm with .

I am using Keyboard Text Replacement but it takes time to type month, day and time.

Is there a utility or other means by which I can quickly insert such date information instead of typing it manually each time?

Comment: It probably would be a rather big coincidence to find an utility which inserts timestamps in your personal Unicode/Emoji format. Also, and maybe I'm missing something here: Even with such a tool you would still need to type the date somehow, so how would this improve the situation?